# How split data from table and insert to new relation?

Tags: mysql

I have table with model and name only this two fields

```
| MODEL |    NAME   |
---------------------
| ABC   |  Abcds123 |
| ABC   |  cde99    |
| ABC   |  oo344    |
| ABC   |  POPOL0   |
| OKL   |  24352233 |
| OKL   |  abcabcab |
| OKL   |  qiueiwow |
| OKL   |  0909o9o9 |
| OKL   |  0909o9o9 |
| OKL   |  0909o9o9 |
```

What i am trying to do is get model value and get all unique name and put to new two tables: models table and items table

```
| ID    | MODEL_NAME |
---------------------
| 1     |  ABC       |
| 2     |  OKL       |

| ID    | MODEL_ID | MODEL_NAME |
---------------------------------
| 1     |  1       | Abcds123
| 2     |  1       | cde99
| 3     |  1       | cde99
| 4     |  2       | 24352233
| 5     |  2       | abcabcab
```

Is this possible ? 
I tried like this :

```
SET @rownr=0;
SELECT DISTINCT 
      `model`, 
      (@rownr := @rownr + 1) AS rowNumber 
FROM `TABLE`  
GROUP BY `model`
```

but i don't know what next and how to get names from the same table

Comment: You have no PK. The problem is essentially insoluble - oh, unless an alphatical arrangement is acceptable.

Comment: We cannot get two tables in a single SQL query. You will need to use multiple queries.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe i can get models and put to new table and then i will get all models with id from new table and get all models name and put to another table with id from first one. Ok let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are willing to accept alphabetical ordering, you could get what you want with these two queries. Output is based on the data in your question.

**Query 1**

```
CREATE TABLE models AS
SELECT (@rownr := @rownr + 1) AS id, model
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT model FROM table1) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownr := 0) v
ORDER BY model;
SELECT * FROM models
```

Output:

```
id  model
1   ABC
2   OKL
```

**Query 2**

```
CREATE TABLE model_names AS
SELECT (@rownr := @rownr + 1) AS id, m.id AS model_id, t1.name AS model_name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT model, name FROM table1 ORDER BY model, name DESC) t1
JOIN models m ON t1.model = m.model
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownr := 0) v
ORDER BY model_id, model_name;
SELECT * FROM model_names
```

Output:

```
id  model_id    model_name
1   1           Abcds123
2   1           cde99
3   1           oo344
4   1           POPOL0
5   2           0909o9o9
6   2           24352233
7   2           abcabcab
8   2           qiueiwow
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5b4c78a67202acd8d22e7b6ff8c11301)