# Split Table and Re-Insert all data properly

Tags: mysql

**Question**

Consider the Table "ProductsStored"

```
        |           ProductsStored               |
        ------------------------------------------
        | id | product | type      | description |
        ------------------------------------------
        | 1  |  AX     | Cleaning  | bla bla bla |
        | 2  |  AB     | Food      | bla bla bla |
        | 3  |  AJ     | Cleaning  | bla bla bla |
        | 4  |  KR     | Food      | bla bla bla |
```

**I want to split this table into two:**

```
|  ProductsType  |
-------------------
| id |  type     | 
------------------
| 1  | Cleaning  | 
| 2  | Food      | 


|           Products                   |
----------------------------------------
| id | product | idType  | description |
----------------------------------------
| 1  |  AX     | 1       | bla bla bla |
| 2  |  AB     | 2       | bla bla bla |
| 3  |  AJ     | 1       | bla bla bla |
| 4  |  KR     | 2       | bla bla bla |
```

**I have several schemas with these kind of tables. The data must be inserted and kept the ID intact in the new two tables.**

I came up with the following code but im missing a part:

## Insert the type of products

```
INSERT INTO `ProductsType` (id, type) SELECT DISTINCT `type` FROM `ProductsStored`
```

## insert the products and make the relationship with its type from "ProductsType"

```
INSERT INTO `Products` (id, product, description, idType) SELECT id,product,description ...(how do I get the idType?)
```

I dont understand how I can get the idType properly. Also, is this approach the correct way to do it?

**References**

[How split data from table and insert to new relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350034/how-split-data-from-table-and-insert-to-new-relation)

This topic almost answers my question but it uses @rownr which I dont understand why he does that. Also it seems he doesnt use proper PK's.

Comment: That's a very long way of saying I want to change the idtype from a string to a numeric. AND do you care what the new idtype number is for example does it matter that Cleaning goes to 1 or would 10 be just as valid for your purposes?

Comment: No. As long as I can make a code that automatically does that for me. Because I have tons of schemas. Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you almost there. Just need a little bit of adjustment as below.

#### Insert the type of products

Set the id to auto increment and use below query.

```
INSERT INTO `ProductsType` (type) SELECT DISTINCT `type` FROM `ProductsStored`
```

#### Insert the products and make the relationship with its type from "ProductsType"

```
INSERT INTO `Products` (id, product, idType, description) SELECT ps.id, ps.product, (SELECT pt.id from ProductsType pt where pt.type=ps.type) as type, ps.description FROM ProductsStored ps
```

That should do it. Cheers.